# Passing mongo data to client in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have a form

```
<form action="/admin/getPublicKey" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Contract</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="publicAddress">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and a corresponding route

```
router.post('/getPublicKey', function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({'local.publicAddress': req.body.publicAddress}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        } else {
            const publicKey = user.local.publicKey;
            res.send(publicKey);
        }
    });
});
```

I just want to click the button and get `publicKey` passed to the client-side. I investigated using `res.redirect` but realised that wouldn't work after reading answers here since I can't pass variables to it.
With `res.send`, I get the publicKey back but it changes the page I'm in to one with the publicKey only.

How can achieve this?

Comment: You should try using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/XMLHttpRequest), [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) or [fetch](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch)

Comment: Perfect that's all I needed (knowing what to google is the key). Cheers!